# C++ - Convert String to Char

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion

I was wondering if there is a way to convert from a string object into a char. For example:

```
string str = "b";
char ch = //convert str to char
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well you can't convert strings of arbitrary length to a single char, you can index the string to get the char you want though: `char ch = str[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly index the string to get the character you want in a same way you index simple arrays.

```
char ch = str[0];
```

This will work for you..